# Trying to update CLLocation if NSUserDefault Exists in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, nsuserdefaults, cloudkit

Originally I was trying to save a CLLocation as a NSUserDefault value before I stored it as a CKRecord in CLoudkit but I got the error: "**defaults.setObject(locationRecord.recordID, forKey: "locationRecordID")" with the reason being "Attempt to set a non-property-list object  as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key locationRecordID**". So now I am trying to save the lat and long as a default and replace the old location in Cloudkit. I am currently getting a '**Thread 1 SIGABRT**' error on the line "**publicDB.fetchRecordWithID((defaults.objectForKey("Location") as! CKRecordID),completionHandler:** " with the reason being "**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x1a1bec968) to 'CKRecordID'.**"

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        self.loc1 = location!
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.004, longitudeDelta: 0.004))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        self.getRecordToUpdate(locations)

        let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
        self.lat1 = lat
        let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
        self.long1 = long

        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
        }
        if error == nil
        {
            print("Location saved")
        }
    }

func getRecordToUpdate(locations:[CLLocation])
    {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var locationRecord:CKRecord

        if defaults.objectForKey("Location") == nil{
            locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
            let locationDict = ["lat": lat1, "lng": long1]//
            defaults.setObject(locationDict, forKey: "Location")//
            self.updateLocationRecord(locationRecord, locations: locations)
            print("new")
        }else{
            let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
            publicDB.fetchRecordWithID((defaults.objectForKey("Location") as! CKRecordID),completionHandler: {  
                (record, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    self.updateLocationRecord(record!, locations: locations)
                    print("fetched record")
                }else{
                    print("Error fetching previous record")
                }
            })
        }
    }
    func updateLocationRecord(locationRecord:CKRecord, locations:[CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
        }
        if error == nil
        {
            print("Location saved")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

You can save NSData to NSUserDefaults. So all you need is to convert your CLLocation object to NSData as follow:

```
// saving your CLLocation object
let locationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(your location here)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationData, forKey: "locationData")

// loading it
if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("locationData") {
    if let loadedLocation = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? CLLocation {
        println(loadedLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        println(loadedLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```